# How to set ScrollX in CDatatable (Reactjs, core-ui)

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I want to use scrollx in cdatatable because i have more field
this is my field

```
    const fields = [{ key: 'No_', _style: { width: '5%'}}
   ,{ key: 'orderNo', _style: { width: '10%'} }
  , { key: 'docdate', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'SalepersonCN', _style: { width: '15%'}}
  , { key: 'No', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'Description', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'VariantCode', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'VariantName', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'TEST1', _style: { width: '10%'} }
  , { key: 'TEST2', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'ShipmentDate', _style: { width: '10%'} }

  , { key: 'VariantCode', _style: { width: '10%'}}
  , { key: 'Quantity', _style: { width: '10%'} }
  , { key: 'TEST3', _style: { width: '10%'} }
  , { key: 'TEST4', _style: { width: '10%'} }
  , { key: 'TEST5', _style: { width: '10%'} }
  , { key: 'TEST6', _style: { width: '100px'}}]
```

i try to change width from % to px but still not work

this is my CDatatable

```
<CContainer>
              <CRow>
                <CCardGroup>
                <CCard>
                  <CCard>
                      </CCardBody>
                    </CCard>
                    <CCardBody>
                    <CDataTable 
                      items={rows}
                      fields={fields}
                      columnFilter
                      tableFilter
                      onColumnFilterChange={setFilters}
                      onFilteredItemsChange={setitems}
                      itemsPerPageSelect
                      itemsPerPage={makeDefaultState.itemsPerPage}
                      hover
                      sorter
                      pagination
                    />
                    </CCardBody>
                    </CCard>
                    </CCardGroup>
              </CRow>
        </CContainer>
```

in the result table not have scrollx and every field auto respond width

Code from: https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/CDataTable/